# Rails 5 - How to fix rmagick -v '2.16.0' issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

In rails 5.0.0, I am trying to run one application but bundle install is not working, it showing an error like

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

 current directory: /home/XYZ/shruthir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rmagick-2.16.0/ext/RMagick
 /home/XYZ/shruthir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20171012-7699-f2np4k.rb extconf.rb
 checking for gcc... yes
 checking for Magick-config... no
 checking for pkg-config... yes
 Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
 Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc'
 to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
 No package 'MagickCore' found
 checking for outdated ImageMagick version (<= 6.4.9)... *** extconf.rb failed ***
 Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
 libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  

 ...

 Gem files will remain installed in /home/XYZ/shruthir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rmagick-2.16.0 for inspection.
 Results logged to /home/XYZ/shruthir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/rmagick-2.16.0/gem_make.out

 An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.16.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
 Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rmagick
```

If I run `gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0'` then it shows an same error like

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

This issue is searched in google and trying to fix by running `sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev` but again it shows an error like

```
 Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libpcre3-dev amd64 2:8.38-3.1                                                                               
   500  Internal Error [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
 E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pcre3/libpcre3-dev_8.38-3.1_amd64.deb  500  Internal Error [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

`sudo apt-get update` logs are like

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                
Hit:4 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x xenial InRelease
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/brightbox/ruby-ng/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                             
Hit:7 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                               
Hit:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                           
Hit:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt xenial-pgdg InRelease                                                 
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                             
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu xenial InRelease                        
Hit:6 http://screenshots.getdeb.net xenial-getdeb InRelease               
Hit:12 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed InRelease [253 kB]
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Fetched 560 kB in 3s (146 kB/s)     
Reading package lists... Done
```

Please help me to fix this `rmagick` issue.

Comment: try this sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev

Comment: As your error suggest, have you tried `sudo apt-get update`? Try that once which update your package list.

Comment: Already tried all these commands but same issue exists.

Answer (score 0):

**Latest Approach**

```
PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16:$PATH"

gem install rmagick
```

**Approach 1**

rmagick gem is not able find PKG_CONFIG_PATH while installing. We need to tell where the path for the ImageMagick exists. It's always better to add in the bash.

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.3-7/lib/pkgconfig
```

**Approach 2**
If the above solution doesn't work  then try this 
 You just have to tell pkg-config where to find the MagickCore.pc file to build the extension.  If you have installed the package ImageMagick-devel using yum the file should be inside the directory /usr/lib/pkgconfig or /usr/lib64/pkgconfig (depending on your architecture)

try this

```
locate /usr/lib64/pkgconfig -name MagickCore.pc
```

or

```
find /usr/lib64/pkgconfig -name MagickCore.pc
```

If the file is there you just have to install rmagick with this command:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH='/usr/lib64/pkgconfig' gem install rmagick
```

Comment: After trying this again I am getting an error like `Can't install RMagick 2.16.0. Can't find MagickWand.h.`

Comment: No. Same issue is happening.

Comment: try to do sudo apt-get update and share the recent logs then

Comment: Done. Updated the question.

Comment: I have updated my answer please check and let me know